# JavaFx my css file is not working

Tags: java, css, javafx

It was working earlier but now here is a screenshot [image: screenshot]

of my running program and it is clearly not. Can somebody help me with this? I am a beginner to JavaFX.

**Analog_clock.java**

```
package analog_clock;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author ishansrivastava
 */
public class Analog_clock extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setCenterX(100.0f);
        circle.setCenterY(100.0f);
        circle.setRadius(50.0f);

        Group g = new Group();
        g.getChildren().add(circle);

        Pane bg = new Pane();
        //bg.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill("-fx-color: #ACACE6", null,null)));
        bg.getChildren().add(g);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bg, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show()cl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**style.css**

```
.Circle
{
    -fx-stroke: #757575; /* sonic silver */
    -fx-fill: #00CC99; /* caribbean green */
}
.pane 
{
    -fx-background-color: #ACACE6; /* maximum blue purple */
}
```

Thank you for helping me out.

**update :**

after changing my css file to this :

```
.circle
{
    -fx-stroke: #757575; /* sonic silver */
    -fx-fill: #00CC99; /* caribbean green */
}
.root
{
    -fx-background-color: #ACACE6; /* maximum blue purple */
}
```

my background appears to be purple where as I have **nothing named *root*** in my code.

Comment: What's the question Erwin? I did not get it.

Comment: why are the colours not appearing as I defined in my css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `id` of the `circle` & `bg`, it should work:

```
circle.setId("circle");`
bg.setId("bg");
```

Then create your `CSS` file:

```
#circle{
    -fx-stroke: #757575; /* sonic silver */
    -fx-fill: #00CC99; /* caribbean green */
}

#bg{
    -fx-background-color: #ACACE6; /* maximum blue purple */
}
```

[image]

And regarding the `root` word, I'm not quite sure, but I think it has a special meaning in JavaFX (specifically `FXML` language), and that's why it has been understood as if you defined your `Pane bg` with that name! However, have a look at [How to understand and use `<fx:root>` in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600926/how-to-understand-and-use-fxroot-in-javafx) it may help.

Comment: You are a LifeSaver. but I have never seen someone writing without a . or # in css file. also please check the update: I made in my question. what can be the reason for that?

Comment: also how would I be able to use different styles for different circles without using # ?

Comment: `root` is a special styleclass for the scene (that can't have a user-defined styleclass).

Comment: @MouseEvent OK.. So my guessing is correct. Cheers.

Comment: @MouseEvent @Yahya why are things not working as they are supposed to, like in the javaFX documentation, to set id, this command is listed, but it is not working `outer_circle.getStyleClass().add("outer");`

Comment: @ErwinSmith My friend, I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923411/understanding-getstyleclass-add-and-a-few-lines-of-code) would help. Otherwise, please post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as you began, there are some points that you have missed, and probably you don't understand how styling works with css.

First of all when you add the syleSheet to your `Scene`, that means you say for the scene: look here is the stylesheet you can use these things from it. So you don't add it them instantly to the components like background, circle etc.

Furthermore, while the Circle is a `Node`, and it implements `Styleable`, you have the method `getStyleClass()` that holds all stylings for the Node(in this case for the Circle), and if you want to add some new styling you can simply do this way: (for example for the circle) `circle.getStyleClass().add("cirle");` Of course this won't work wothout setting the stylesheet.

One more thing, you can specify the stylesheets for every node, os if you want you can use one stylesheet for the `Pane` and an other for the `Circle`.But usually us use stylesheets at parent nodes, then add styles for the children separately.

So this is how you can simply use the styling. I hope this is understandable.

Comment: a little bit un-understandable but I will get back to it as I am not following a tutorial (as advised by over 30 people on reddit) and just learning by doing and reading the documentation so it will take a few days

Comment: I was unable to style components in my dialog and "that means you say for the scene: look here is the stylesheet you can use these things from it" helped me to understand/remember that I did not call `scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles.css");` on my dialog's Scene

Answer (score 0):

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(Analog_clock.class.getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
```